# Nilpotent groups and 2-generated subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, infinite-groups

Do you know an example of a *$2$-locally nipotent* group $G$ which is not *locally nilpotent*?

**$2$-locally nilpotent:** every subgroup which is generated by $2$ elements is nilpotent.

**locally nilpotent:** every finitely generated subgroup is nilpotent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The groups referred to in YCor's answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267300/) are infinite $d$-generator $p$-groups in which every $(d-1)$-generator subgroup is finite, and hence nilpotent since it is a $p$-group. So they provide examples, although it might be hard to find out much about them.

Comment: Why are these groups not locally nilpotent? (I guess a Burnside group cannot be nilpotent, but cannot see why just now.)

Comment: More generally a finitely generated solvable torsion group is finite. You can prove it by induction on the derived length. $G/G'$ is finitely generated abelian and hence finite, so $G'$ is finitely generated, and the result follows by induction.

Comment: @user1729 It's an exercise to show that every infinite finitely generated solvable group has a finite index subgroup having $\mathbf{Z}$ as quotient.